# Parsing Strings (JAVA)

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to complete this assignment, but I'm stuck on how to proceed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter input string: ");
            String userInput = scan.nextLine();

            if (userInput.contains(","))
            {
                System.out.println("First word:  " + userInput.split(",")[0]);
                System.out.println("Second word:" + userInput.split(",")[1]);
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
            else if (!userInput.contains(","))
            {
                System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");

            }
            else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

[image]

** I've fixed the issue with the quit, still need help with the weird whitespace.

Comment: Hint: does "q" contain a comma? How do you expect to get to your final "else if" when `userInput` is "q"?

Comment: Thank you! I've put the quit at the top. Still not sure how to fix the odd whitespace.

Comment: It's not clear to me what's wrong.  What's weird about the whitespace?

Comment: The program I'm submitting to keeps telling me I have an extra space after the first word and before the second word.

Comment: There's an extra space because that is what you typed after `Golden`. Look here: `Golden , Monkey`

Comment: If you need to remove the whitespace when you split, you can try `userInput.split("\\s*,\\s*")`.  The `"\\s*"` part is an expression that means "any amount of white space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never actually goes to the last "else if", because "q" doesn't contain a comma, so only the second "else if" is accessed. Also, you aren't removing the spaces in your string, you still keep them after spliting the words.